# Replacing Index values using regex matching

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to do string replacement in an index within a Pandas Series. However, at the moment it isn't matching or finding the substring and replacing it with a given value.

My current series:

`index
@12456    string_1
@54324    string_2
@34566    string_3
@57453    string_4
@67645    string_5
Name: value, dtype: object`

To this, I am trying to remove the '@' sign from the index values.

I'm using:

```
series.replace(to_replace={'index': {'@': ''}})
```

however, it doesn't seem to match the substring and returns the initial series. What am I missing and how would I achieve my expected result?

My pandas version is currently at 0.15.

P.S. I have also tried:

```
series.replace(to_replace={'index': {r'@': ''}})
series.replace(to_replace={'index': {r'\@': ''}})
```

## UPDATE

Some answers are coming in that solve the specific issue, but I need a more general case. So, if the series is:

`index   other_index
@12456  1              string_1
@54324  2              string_2
@34566  3              string_3
@57453  4              string_4
@67645  5              string_5
Name: value, dtype: object`

How would I apply the same operation to the index here? Which would work for both the first measure and this other measure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
series.index = series.index.map(lambda v: v.replace('@', ''))
```

or

```
series.index = series.index.str.replace('@', '')
```

For multi-index, here is a possible solution (not as pretty though):

```
# setting up the indices and the series
arrays = [['@str1', '@str2'], [1, 2]]
ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=['index', 'other_index'])
series = pd.Series(['s1', 's2'], index=ind)

# index  other_index
# @str1  1              s1
# @str2  2              s2
# dtype: object

vals = zip(*series.index.get_values()) ## values of indices reshaped into a list of tuples
# [('@str1', '@str2'), (1L, 2L)]

# find out where is the index that we want to change
pos = series.index.names.index('index')
# now we can modify the tuple by replacing the strings we do not want
vals[pos] = tuple([x.replace('@', '') for x in vals[pos]])

# Re-create the multi-index
series.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(vals, names=series.index.names)

print series
# index  other_index
# str1   1              s1
# str2   2              s2
# dtype: object
```

Comment: I need to be able to match any specific character unfortunately

Comment: then dynamically allocate the '@' in 'Julien Spronck''s code. x being your symbol: series.index = series.index.map(lambda v: v.replace(x, ''))

Comment: @Rambatino I changed this solution to work with multi-indices ... let me know if it helps

Comment: Thank-you very much :)